# How to access a macro from a string containing its name

Tags: c, string, macros

In C, if I have

```
#define NUMBER_TWO 2
char* string = "NUMBER_TWO";
```

How can I get from `string` to the value 2?

Comment: Short and only answer is: You can't.

Comment: With that said, why do you need it? What's the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you have a macro? Why do you represent the macro name as a string? Right now this os too much of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for us to be able to actually help you with the real problem you try to solve.

Comment: Lolo, Is not `if (strcmp(string, "NUMBER_TWO") == 0) value = NUMBER_TWO;` sufficient?

Comment: I see I should have provided more background info to my pbl. I have hundreds of such macros and a file in which the user can list the macro names that should be selected. I generate these macro names with some scripts. Reading through the answers, I think the simplest is to have my script _also_ generate an array with all these macro names as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps OP is interesting is some macro code abuse?

Use `#macro_parameter` to form the *string* `"macro_argument"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_TWO 2
#define NUMBER_THREE 3
#define NUMBER_FOUR 4
#define TEST_AND_RETURN(s, m) \
    do { if (strcmp((s), #m) == 0) return (m); } while (0)

int string_to_value(const char *s) {
  TEST_AND_RETURN(s, NUMBER_TWO);   // Only 1 coding of NUMBER_TWO
  TEST_AND_RETURN(s, NUMBER_THREE);
  // Maybe the clear way instead, or are 2 NUMBER_FOUR a concern?
  if (strcmp(s, "NUMBER_FOUR") == 0) return NUMBER_FOUR;
  return -1;
}

int main() {
  char* string = "NUMBER_TWO";
  printf("%d\n", string_to_value(string));
  printf("%d\n", string_to_value("NUMBER_THREE"));
  printf("%d\n", string_to_value("NUMBER_FOUR"));
}
```

Output

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: Don't know whether to upvote or downvote. ;)

Comment: @Schwern When a coder is trying to be clever rather than clear (both being subjective), seems to make sense to _walk_ that clever tendency toward clarity as the most receptive approach.

Answer (score 2):

`#define NUMBER_TWO 2` doesn't even exist at runtime.

In theory, it's even unknown to the compiler proper, having been handled by the tokenizer.

What this means is that you'll need to some create some kind of lookup yourself.

```c
if ( strcmp( string, "NUMBER_TWO" ) == 0 ) {
   ... NUMBER_TWO ...
} else {
   ... ??? ...
}
```

Of course, if you had to look up many, a better approach should be used than a series of `strcmp` calls.

Answer (score 1):

`#define NUMBER_TWO 2` is part of the pre-processor. `NUMBER_TWO` is replaced with `2` in the source code and then compiled. No trace of `NUMBER_TWO` exists at runtime.

You have to write something which takes a string and returns specific macros. How best this is solve depends on what you're doing with the value. If you have a lot of macros you wish to access via a string, one simple way would be to put them into a hash.

```
#define NUMBER_TWO 2
char* string = "NUMBER_TWO";

// This is just an example. You'll have to write a hash,
// or better use a library such as GLib.
IntHash *stuff = int_hash_new();

int_hash_insert(stuff, "NUMBER_TWO", NUMBER_TWO);

int num = int_hash_fetch(stuff, string);
```

But at this point you can skip the macro and initialize the hash directly.

```
char* string = "NUMBER_TWO";

IntHash *stuff = hash_new();

int_hash_insert(stuff, "NUMBER_TWO", 2);
int_hash_insert(stuff, "NUMBER_THREE", 3);
int_hash_insert(stuff, "NUMBER_FOUR", 4);

int num = int_hash_fetch(stuff, string);
```

Comment: Please fix the strings quotation marks

Comment: @EugeneSh. Done. Does the edit button not work?

Comment: You had just done one or more edits, meaning 1) you were still around, 2) having someone else do an edit could conflict with a new edit of yours. It's not uncommon to ask for edits rather than making them in those circumstances.